# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable even after multiple tries

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX9MY.png)

I cannot figure out how I can get this formula to work. Any help is very appreciated! :)

I tried appling everything that is in the picture. But I berly have any knowlage of coding.

Comment: Please [don't post code/errors/data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: You should start by removing all those pointless parentheses. If you write something like `1(2)`, to Python that means you're trying to call a function `1` with parameters `2`, since there's no operator inbetween the two parts of what you want to be an expression. You can't just add parentheses around things willy-nilly. Also, unlike in some forms of math, something like `(x)(y)` does not mean `x * y` - you have to write operators explicitly, or use functions.

Comment: You need to post code and errors as text. You can copy / paste. Don't expect us to hand copy from an image. That said, its in this fragment `...2)(1...`. You didn't put an operator there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An operator is missing as shown [in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQhVS.png) that's why it raisea s not callable error. having (1)(2)(this is seen as a function call in the interpreter) doesn't mean (1) * (2) in python,